# Mysql:How to concatenate more than one row into single row with diffrent field name?

Tags: php, mysql

```
id  Subject   mark   Year
-------------------------
1   Maths      32    2008
1   Science    40    2009
1   Science    45    2008
1   English    50    2009
1   English    60    2008
```

I am looking for a result like this:

```
id  Maths   Science   English
-----------------------------
1   32      40 & 45   50 & 60
```

Please advise. I am using MySQL.

Comment: In pure SQL or can PHP be used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [@Mark suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015786/mysqlhow-to-concatenate-more-than-one-row-into-single-row-with-diffrent-field-na/3015826#3015826), [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) can give you the following result:

```
SELECT   id, subject, GROUP_CONCAT(mark SEPARATOR ' & ') marks
FROM     results 
GROUP BY id, subject;
+------+---------+---------+
| id   | subject | marks   |
+------+---------+---------+
|    1 | English | 50 & 60 |
|    1 | Maths   | 32      |
|    1 | Science | 40 & 45 |
+------+---------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

From this test case:

```
CREATE TABLE results (id int, subject varchar(10), mark int);

INSERT INTO results VALUES (1, 'Maths', 32);
INSERT INTO results VALUES (1, 'Science', 40);
INSERT INTO results VALUES (1, 'Science', 45);
INSERT INTO results VALUES (1, 'English', 50);
INSERT INTO results VALUES (1, 'English', 60);
```

However another way to tackle the problem would be by using as sub query for each subject:

```
SELECT    r.id,
          (SELECT   GROUP_CONCAT(r_eng.mark SEPARATOR ' & ')
           FROM     results r_eng
           WHERE    r_eng.subject = 'English' AND r_eng.id = r.id) English,
          (SELECT   GROUP_CONCAT(r_eng.mark SEPARATOR ' & ') 
           FROM     results r_eng
           WHERE    r_eng.subject = 'Maths' AND r_eng.id = r.id) Maths,
          (SELECT   GROUP_CONCAT(r_eng.mark SEPARATOR ' & ') 
           FROM     results r_eng
           WHERE    r_eng.subject = 'Science' AND r_eng.id = r.id) Science
FROM      results r
GROUP BY  r.id;
```

Which will give the following result:

```
+------+---------+-------+---------+
| id   | English | Maths | Science |
+------+---------+-------+---------+
|    1 | 50 & 60 | 32    | 40 & 45 |
+------+---------+-------+---------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Further to the comments, it looks like you need to take the `year` field in consideration. Luckily the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function takes an `ORDER BY` clause which we can use. Let's start from a new test case with the year field:

```
CREATE TABLE results (id int, subject varchar(10), mark int, year int);

INSERT INTO results VALUES (1, 'Maths', 32, 2008);
INSERT INTO results VALUES (1, 'Science', 40, 2009);
INSERT INTO results VALUES (1, 'Science', 45, 2008);
INSERT INTO results VALUES (1, 'English', 50, 2009);
INSERT INTO results VALUES (1, 'English', 60, 2008);

SELECT * FROM results;
+------+---------+------+------+
| id   | subject | mark | year |
+------+---------+------+------+
|    1 | Maths   |   32 | 2008 |
|    1 | Science |   40 | 2009 |
|    1 | Science |   45 | 2008 |
|    1 | English |   50 | 2009 |
|    1 | English |   60 | 2008 |
+------+---------+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then we would be able to use the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function with the `ORDER BY` clause as follows:

```
SELECT   id, 
         subject, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(mark ORDER BY year SEPARATOR ' & ') marks, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(year ORDER BY year SEPARATOR ' & ') years
FROM     results 
GROUP BY id, subject;

+------+---------+---------+-------------+
| id   | subject | marks   | years       |
+------+---------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | English | 60 & 50 | 2008 & 2009 |
|    1 | Maths   | 32      | 2008        |
|    1 | Science | 45 & 40 | 2008 & 2009 |
+------+---------+---------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Finally, to `GROUP BY` everything in one horizontal row, we can use the subquery technique that we used in the earlier example:

```
SELECT    r.id,
          (SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(r_eng.mark ORDER BY year SEPARATOR ' & ') 
           FROM    results r_eng
           WHERE   r_eng.subject = 'English' AND r_eng.id = r.id) English,
          (SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(r_eng.year ORDER BY year SEPARATOR ' & ')
            FROM   results r_eng
            WHERE  r_eng.subject = 'English' AND r_eng.id = r.id) Years_English,
          (SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(r_eng.mark ORDER BY year SEPARATOR ' & ')
           FROM    results r_eng
           WHERE   r_eng.subject = 'Maths' AND r_eng.id = r.id) Maths,
          (SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(r_eng.year ORDER BY year SEPARATOR ' & ')
            FROM   results r_eng
            WHERE  r_eng.subject = 'Maths' AND r_eng.id = r.id) Years_Maths,
          (SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(r_eng.mark ORDER BY year SEPARATOR ' & ')
           FROM    results r_eng
           WHERE   r_eng.subject = 'Science' AND r_eng.id = r.id) Science,
          (SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(r_eng.year ORDER BY year SEPARATOR ' & ')
            FROM   results r_eng
            WHERE  r_eng.subject = 'Science' AND r_eng.id = r.id) Years_Science
FROM      results r
GROUP BY  r.id;
```

Which will return the following:

```
+----+---------+---------------+-------+-------------+---------+---------------+
| id | English | Years_English | Maths | Years_Maths | Science | Years_Science |
+----+---------+---------------+-------+-------------+---------+---------------+
|  1 | 60 & 50 | 2008 & 2009   | 32    | 2008        | 45 & 40 | 2008 & 2009   |
+----+---------+---------------+-------+-------------+---------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

If you wanted the marks and the years ordered in descending order, you could simply add the `DESC` keyword after each `ORDER BY year`.

Comment: I need results based on year and then I want to display in one horizontal row.

Comment: ID SUBJECT MARKS YEAR<br>
1  English 50 & 60 2008 & 2009

I need like this

Comment: @subakaran: What do you mean exactly by "based on year"? ... You mean that the earliest marks should appear first?

Comment: Hi daniel, Thank you so much. Just I check with you something.
am using more than five tables with JOIN query and retrieve results like yours. Like your results, I want to display more than 300 row. so is it possible to display like this. now I cannot test. Because Project has in my office local server. how do you feel execute time. Then can you display year also.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have four year results. so I want to generate report . So I need to show those who have scored how much marks in every subject based on year. 

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Would it be easier to `GROUP_CONCAT(some_field SEPARATOR ' & ')`, rather than using `REPLACE` ?

Comment: @pilcrow: Well, I guess so :) ... Let me update... Fixed, much neater now... Thanks @pilcrow :)

Comment: Excellent Daniel. Exactly I have needed your last answer.
You have satisfied my exact idea.
I like the last answer.

That's good.
So now I fell, I need to learn more & more.

Thanks Daniel

Comment: @subakaran: I'm glad this helped :) ... 300 rows is not a lot, and you'll have no performance problems for sure with that amount of rows.

Comment: Thanks for your advice

Thanks. I keep touch with you.

Comment: @subakaran: You may want to mark the answer as "accepted" by clicking on the green tick on the left, if it was helpful in solving your problem :)

Comment: ya I have done. This is the first time I used this forum. very helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

For the first step, take a look at the [group_concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) functiopn in mysql, it may be of some help

```
SELECT `id`,
       `subject`,
       group_concat( `mark`
                     ORDER BY `year` DESC
                     SEPARATOR ' & '
                   ) marks
  FROM `subjects` 
 GROUP BY `id`,
          `subject`
```

**UPDATE**
Managed to get as far as

```
SELECT `id`,
       IF (`subject` = 'English', `marks`, NULL) AS English,
       IF (`subject` = 'Maths', `marks`, NULL) AS Maths,
       IF (`subject` = 'Science', `marks`, NULL) AS Science
  FROM ( SELECT `id`, 
                `subject`, 
                group_concat( `mark` 
                              ORDER BY `year` DESC 
                              SEPARATOR ' & ' 
                            ) marks 
           FROM `subjects`  
          GROUP BY `id`, 
                   `subject` 
         ) x
GROUP BY `id`,
         `subject`
```

which returns

```
+----+---------+-------+---------+
| id | English | Maths | Science |
+----+---------+-------+---------+
|  1 | 50 & 60 | NULL  | NULL    |
|  1 | NULL    | 32    | NULL    |
|  1 | NULL    | NULL  | 40 & 45 |
+----+---------+-------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

but can't quite get that last grouping right to return it all as a single row.
Don't know if anybody else can help me get the final step right when taking this approach to the problem.... ordinarily, I'd return the result to PHP "as is", and do the final grouping there; but a complete MySQL solution would be interesting.

Comment: I need Mysql query only. Thanks for immediate reply

Comment: hi Mark, Thanks for your reply. I think , I need to learn more about CONCAT() function from mysql. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got solution from Mr.Daniel. Thanks. "IF" condition is also good.